# I need portrait only for all screen sizes except xlarge screen size which needs to be landscape or portrait

Tags: android

I cannot seem to find a solution to fix everything in portrait except
xlarge (tablet screens) which needs to be fixed in landscape or portrait.

Comment: use this key word in your Manifest "android:screenOrientation="portrait""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreate`

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) < Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

The sdk target in your AndroidManifest.xml must be Android 3.0 or greater to access the SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE constant. Otherwise replace it with the constant it represents: 4

Answer (score 2):

add folder in your res as below and use 2 different xml layout

`res/layout/` // put all your layout here for your normal devices

`res/layout-xlarge/`   // layout for extra large in portrait orientation

and

`res/layout-xlarge-land/` // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

Comment: i want to set set my orientation only in portrait for sample devices. and landscape and portrait for tablets.
so if i print "android:screenOrientation="portrait" to get only portrait for sample devices, i will never use res/layout-xlarge-land/ for tablet?

Comment: use it this wont affect your normal phones/deviec orientation.

Comment: sorry it doesn't work, i must remove android:screenOrientation="portrait" , to get the xlarge land layout.
But as i say it must be only in portrait mode if sample device, so i can't remove this line

Comment: what is sample device. say that as normal phone. use Matt M answer for  programatically change orientation.